# Create a label inside a frame

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to create a label inside a frame. I didn't see a way to drop the label on the frame, so I tried to modify the xaml by putting the label inside frame.

It was:

```
<Frame Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="272" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128"/>
        <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,95,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

I changed it to:

```
    <Frame Content="Frame" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="272" Margin="10,10,0,0"      VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="128">
                <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="67,95,0,0"     VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    </Frame>
```

However it gives me the error below:

```
Cannot add content to an object of type "Frame".
```

Is it really the case that we cannot add content to a frame in WPF or is there something I am not doing right in my adding of a label to a frame?

Comment: Why don't you use the Content property of Frame which itself allows you to define some text. Probably you can bind this property to your viewmodel

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't it hold only one content? You declare Frame with a content property and insert a label which is another.

Comment: I just dragged and dropped them on to the main window. If I should set any properties what are they and where to set?

Comment: remove Content="Frame" in Frame control

Comment: After reading msdn, I find that Frame is used for navigation but not for contain other content although it is a ContentControl, However ,I think you can achieve this by customize its ControlTemplate  and DataTemplate